# How to create a ChaCha-based RNG in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a cryptographically secure random number generator in a Rust program based on ChaCha.
Currently I have

```
let mut rand = ChaChaRng::new_unseeded();
let rand_num = &rand.gen_range(1, 7);
```

The problem is that this results in the same random numbers being produced, because (I think) 'new_unseeded()' just uses 0 as the seed.

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/rand/0.5.0/rand/prng/chacha/struct.ChaChaRng.html) I found doesn't have any examples
Is there a method I could call instead so that rand will be seeded by the system in an appropriately random way? (Possibly something like the from_entropy() method?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in the more recent versions of the `rand` crate, the ChaCha generator has moved out to a companion crate `rand_chacha`. Here's usage:

```rust
use rand_chacha::ChaChaRng;
use rand_chacha::rand_core::SeedableRng;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rand = ChaChaRng::from_entropy();
    let rand_num = &rand.gen_range(1..7);
    println!("{}", rand_num);
}
```